# How to get product price after a discount was applied

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, price, csv

I tried to get the  **product price** after a **catalog price rules** was applied and i can't.

The code that i use to do this:

```
//load product by id
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());

    //get promo_price
    $promo_price = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->calcProductPriceRule($product,$product->getPrice());
```

and this:

```
$promo_price = $product->getPrice() - $product->getDiscountAmount();
```

But this code  returns me NULL.

Does anyone know how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my issue like this:

```
$customerId = $coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'];
            //Load customer to take the customer group id
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
            $group= $customer->getGroupId();

        //Get price after a discount per customer 
                $discounted_price = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->calcProductPriceRule($product
                ->setStoreId(1)
                ->setCustomerGroupId($grup),
                $product->getPrice()
                );
```

Answer (score 3):

We use this to get an updated product price

```
<?php
$_product->getPrice();

$_product->getFinalPrice();

//Here you can get the catalog rule applied price like:
$store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$discounted_price = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')->getRulePrice(
    Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp($store_id),
    Mage::app()->getStore($store_id)->getWebsiteId(),
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
    $_product->getId()
);


if ($discountedPrice === false) { // if no rule applied for the product
    $discountedPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
} else {
    $discountedPrice = number_format($discountedPrice,2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$regularPrice = number_format($product->getPrice(), 2);

$discountedPrice = number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2);

$specialPrice = number_format($product->getSpecialPrice(), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use type **int**

```
$promo_price = (int)$product->getPrice() - (int)$product->getDiscountAmount();
```